# How to compare 2 files and output desired content to third file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have 2 input files.

File 1 content as (`file1`):

```
"BRGTEST-242" a.txt
"BRGTEST-240" a.txt
"BRGTEST-219" e.txt
```

File 2 content as (`file2`):

```
"BRGTEST-244" a.txt
"BRGTEST-244" b.txt
"BRGTEST-231" c.txt
"BRGTEST-231" d.txt
"BRGTEST-221" e.txt
```

I want to get final output as (`file3`):

```
BRGTEST-244 is depdendent on BRGTEST-242 for file a.txt    
BRGTEST-244 is depdendent on BRGTEST-240 for file a.txt    
BRGTEST-221 is dependent on BRGTEST-219 for the file e.txt
```

How to write the shell script logic for this? I tried using `awk` but could not get the results I want.

Comment: cross-posted https://askubuntu.com/q/1056275/283843

Comment: The cross-post is supposedly being deleted on AU, I've gone ahead and reopened it here.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Awk (gawk), which supports multidimensional arrays, the logic appears to be:

```
gawk '
  NR==FNR {
    a[$2][++c[$2]] = $1; next
  } 
  $2 in a {
    for (i in a[$2]) 
      print $1 " is dependent on " a[$2][i] " for " $2
  }
' File1 File2
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-242" for a.txt
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-240" for a.txt
"BRGTEST-221" is dependent on "BRGTEST-219" for e.txt
```

If you need to remove the quotes as well:

```
gawk '
  NR==FNR {
    a[$2][++c[$2]] = substr($1,2,length($1)-2); next
  } 
  $2 in a {
    for (i in a[$2]) 
      print substr($1,2,length($1)-2) " is dependent on " a[$2][i] " for " $2
  }
' File1 File2
BRGTEST-244 is dependent on BRGTEST-242 for a.txt
BRGTEST-244 is dependent on BRGTEST-240 for a.txt
BRGTEST-221 is dependent on BRGTEST-219 for e.txt
```

Comment: Nice work as always.

Comment: @slm thanks - and thanks for clarifying the OP's requirement above

Comment: For passer by's the `NR==FNR` - several good examples and walkthroughs of what that does - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-is-nr-fnr-in-awk.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line1; do
  f21=$(echo $line1 | cut -d" " -f1)
  f22=$(echo $line1 | cut -d" " -f2)
  #echo "outside: $f21 -- $f22"

  while read line2; do
    f11=$(echo $line2 | cut -d" " -f1)
    f12=$(echo $line2 | cut -d" " -f2)
    #echo "inside: $f11 -- $f12"

    if [ "$f22" == "$f12" ]; then
      echo "$f21 is dependent on $f11 for file $f22"
    fi

  done < file1
done < file2
```

#### Example

```
./parsy.bash
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-242" for file a.txt
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-240" for file a.txt
"BRGTEST-221" is dependent on "BRGTEST-219" for file e.txt
```

#### How it works

I left in this script 2 `echo ...` commands which you can uncomment to see visually how this script is walking through the other 2 files. When you uncomment them you'll see this output:

```
$ ./parsy.bash | head -10
outside: "BRGTEST-244" -- a.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-242" -- a.txt
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-242" for file a.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-240" -- a.txt
"BRGTEST-244" is dependent on "BRGTEST-240" for file a.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-219" -- e.txt
outside: "BRGTEST-244" -- b.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-242" -- a.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-240" -- a.txt
inside: "BRGTEST-219" -- e.txt
```

The key in doing this is recognizing that you need to walk through the contents of `file2` and see if each element matches based on your conditions what's in `file1`. In order to do this, you have to nest a loop, inside of another loop.

Once you have this structure, and the data parsed accordingly, a simple `if` statement can be used to determine if the 2nd column from `file1` and `file2` are a match, if so, we `echo` the message using the pieces we've collected.